# I want to add the values of two cells present in the same column based on their " index = somevalue"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with the column "Key" as index  like below:

`Key`
`Prediction`

`C11D0       0
C11D1       8
C12D0       1
C12D1       5
C13D0       3
C13D1       9
C14D0       4
C14D1       9
C15D0       5
C15D1       3
C1D0        5
C2D0        7
C3D0        4
C4D0        1
C4D1        9`

I want to add the values of two cells in Prediction column when their "index = something". The logic is I want to add the values whose index matches for upto 4 letters. Example: indexes having "C11D0 & C11D1" or having "C14D0 & C14D1" ? Then the output will be:

`Operation`
`Addition Result`

`C11D0+C11D1     8
C12D0+C12D1     6
C13D0+C13D1    12`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

- you can use `isin` function.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'value':[1,2,1,3,7,1]})
df[df.id.isin([1,5,6])].value.sum()
```

output:

> 9

- for your case

```
idx = ['C11D0', 'C11D1']
print(df[df.Key.isin(idx)].Prediction.sum()) #outputs 8
```

Answer (score 0):

First set key as a column if it is the index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then you can use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['key'].isin(["C11D0","C11D1"]),'Prediciton'].sum()
```

You can  also create a function for it:

```
def sum_select_df(key_list,df):
    return pd.concat([df[df['Key'].isin(['C'+str(key)+'D1','C'+str(key)+'D0'])] for key in key_list])['Prediction'].sum()

sum_select_df([11,14],df)
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but what if I want to perform this operation for every row? The logic is I want to add the values whose index matches for upto 4 letters. Example: indexes having "C11D0 & C11D1" or having "C14D0 & C14D1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution, slightly different from the other answers so far. I tried to make it pretty self-explanatory, but let me know if you have any questions!

```
import numpy as np # only used to generate test data
import pandas as pd
import itertools as itt

start_inds = ["C11D0", "C11D1", "C12D0", "C12D1", "C13D0", "C13D1", "C14D0", "C14D1",
        "C15D0", "C15D1", "C1D0", "C2D0", "C3D0", "C4D0", "C4D1"]
test_vals = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=len(start_inds))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test_vals, index=start_inds, columns=["prediction"])

ind_combs = itt.combinations(df.index.array, 2)

sum_records = ((f"{ind1}+{ind2}", df.loc[[ind1, ind2], "prediction"].sum())
               for (ind1, ind2) in ind_combs if ind1[:4] == ind2[:4])

res_ind, res_vals = zip(*sum_records)

res_df = pd.DataFrame(data=res_vals, index=res_ind, columns=["sum_result"])
```